# Guard page is triggered right after VirtualProtect

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I have a DWORD value that I want to monitor changes, so I decided to use a guard page.

The problem is that the `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION` exception is triggered right after marking the memory as `PAGE_GUARD` using `VirtualProtect`:

```
DWORD* lpAddress = (DWORD*)0xDEADBEEF;

void test()
{
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(0x1, MyHandler);

    DWORD oldprotection;
    VirtualProtect(lpAddress, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD, &oldProtection);

    //Here, the STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION is triggered and MyHandler is immediately called

    MessageBox(NULL, L"Just a test", L"", MB_OK);
}

LONG WINAPI MyHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExc)
{
    if(pExc->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION)
    {
       //Immediately called after VirtualProtect
       //If I try to use VirtualProtect again, it will also immediately trigger MyHandler
    }

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}
```

I've read something about that `VirtualProtect` is accessing the address inside its function body so that's why the trigger happens (first trigger is from `VirtualProtect` itself), but I'm not sure.

Is there any way to avoid this?
Or maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VirtualProtect` protects the entire 4K page (or possibly pages) that contain the 4 bytes you want to guard.  Any access to any part of that page (not just the address you want to guard) will result in the guard page alarm to trigger.

If you just want to monitor those 4 bytes a guard page isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, but actually makes sense now, from the lots of tests I've done. May you guide me on this situation? What is a better way to do this? Any concept or documentation is good for me

Comment: @hendoe - are you have knowledge about threads, which can access this variable ? if say we know that only one specific thread do this - exist solution with `DrX` registers

Comment: @RbMm Debug registers would work but what if I wanted to watch access to multiple variables? Since they raise a single step exception, how can I identify which one has been accessed?

Comment: @RbMm I think I can check DrX values since they hold the addresses, right?

Comment: @hendoe - with Dr registers you can watch maximum 4 memory locations, which is fired - visible in [Dr6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register#DR6_-_Debug_status)